# Session drop to -77% in Chrome browser

Tags: google-analytics, google-chrome, google-tag-manager, session, page-views

I have used GTM and GA to implement analytics for one of my client.
Last week all of a sudden there is a session drop to -77% in chrome browser.
This is the top browser that most of the sessions are hit on for my client.

I have checked manually on this version of chrome browser, and found nothing weird. I could see the website functionality is perfect and my tracking as well looks good on all the pages.

Is anyone is facing the session drop in chrome browser recently?

Comment: Are you sure it is just chrome that is effected?  How do you know?

Comment: I have seen in GA. The drop happened in only chrome. it has showed me the version as 54.0...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking others for their experience does not lend itself to this format.

Comment: What could be the possible reasons for this? I am facing the same issue. Almost 60% direct traffic is dropped after website revamp.